# How do I import data from a .bat file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I created a .bat file (import_file.bat):

```
set database_name=nome_db
mysql –u root --password=pass --database %database_name% < c:/import_geco/sql_svuta.sql
mysql –u root --password=pass --database %database_name% < c:/import_geco/carica_dati.sql
```

From the command line, in the MySQL bin directory I entered:

```
mysql/bin>c:/import_db/import_file.bat
```

... but it doesn't work, instead it returns MySQL help info.

If I create a .bat file to export table (export.bat):

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -u root nome_db nome_tabella  > c:/backup_db/export.sql
```

... and enter at the command line:

```
mysql/bin>c:/import_db/export.bat
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

You get the help file because you have a malformed command. You are attempting to pipe something to the command line. YOu probably need to use the `-e` (--execute) command, and you can either pipe the file or use `LOAD DATA FILE`

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: thanks, i add in bat file the -e:
set database_name=nome_db
mysql -e –u root --password=pass --database %database_name% < c:/import_geco/sql_svuta.sql
mysql -e –u root --password=pass --database %database_name% < c:/import_geco/carica_dati.sql

but it doesn' work.. Can you help me to correct the bat file?

Comment: I can't, but here is the syntax for `load data` with an example to load a data file. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html ) the example is within the context of mysql shell, so for your purposes, you would invoke the -e option, and then include the proper MYSQL command. You can't just include the -e option and expect it to work: you need to actually give a mysql command after that. See the first reference in the documentation for examples of how this would be done. Once you figure this out, ONLY THEN would you put that in a batch file.