# How do I create a script to run MySQL command line?

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-7, command-line

I'm trying to import about 20 .csv files into MySQL and I'm fed up with doing it via phpmyadmin's import gui.

Is there a way to do this by batch without typing on the command line? i.e. a script that will run when double clicked (Windows). What I want is:

1. I have files like porsche.csv, ferrari.csv etc
2. I want to import each of these into tables with the same name (i.e. porsche, ferrari)
3. Empty the table before importing the text file (using `delete` flag). How does it handle new fields?
4. Ignore first line (header).

From what I've gathered so far: we use `mysqlimport`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

I'll try to fiddle around with the options and see if I can get something working.

Comment: Clickable from a Mac desktop?  Windows?  BeOS?  :)  mysqlimport would work nicely, really it's a question of what scripts are available in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the easiest way is to use a batch script.

Read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html) on available options.

The batch script would look something like:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\

mysqlimport ...
```

Other related questions:

- [Import multiple CSV files into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696343/import-multiple-csv-files-into-mysql)
- [How do I import data from a .bat file in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232240/how-do-i-import-data-from-a-bat-file-in-mysql)

Comment: Trying to do a `mysqlimport --local "C:\Users\Desktop\dude.csv"` but the file cannot be found. Are we limited to the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\` directory?

Comment: @meiryo Not at all. That just points to the directory that contains your `mysql` instance.